# How to use longtable package?

Tags: tables, longtable

I am trying to use the `longtable` package and I cannot get it to work. I have pasted my code below, can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{r r r r r r r r r r r r r}
\caption{This table shows the volatges and temperatures of the cell immediately before and immediately after cell failure}

Time & Voltage & Current & Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Plates 1 & Plates 2 & Calroimeter 1& Calorimeter 2& Calorimeter 3 & Calorimeter 4 & Insulation 1 & Insulation 2    0     & 10.839 & 0     & 111.5 & 109.6 & 89.3  & 87.8  & 59.5  & 57.9  & 54.9  & 55.6  & 29.6  & 19 \\
200   & 10.854 & 0     & 111.6 & 109.6 & 89.3  & 87.9  & 59.5  & 57.9  & 54.9  & 55.6  & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 10.869 & 0     & 111.7 & 109.8 & 89.3  & 87.9  & 59.6  & 58    & 54.8  & 55.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
600   & 10.898 & 0     & 111.8 & 109.9 & 89.3  & 88    & 59.5  & 58    & 54.9  & 55.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
799   & 10.903 & 0     & 111.9 & 109.9 & 89.3  & 88    & 59.6  & 58    & 54.8  & 55.6  & 29.5  & 19 \\
0     & 10.916 & 0     & 112.1 & 110.1 & 89.5  & 88.1  & 59.7  & 58.1  & 54.9  & 55.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
200   & 10.901 & 0     & 112.2 & 110.2 & 89.5  & 88.1  & 59.7  & 58.1  & 54.9  & 55.6  & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 10.569 & 0     & 112.4 & 110.4 & 89.5  & 88.1  & 59.7  & 58.1  & 54.9  & 55.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
600   & 7.6   & 0     & 112.4 & 110.4 & 89.7  & 88.1  & 59.7  & 58.1  & 54.9  & 55.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
799   & 4.861 & 0     & 112.5 & 110.4 & 90.6  & 88.1  & 59.8  & 58.1  & 54.9  & 55.7  & 29.6  & 19 \\
0     & 2.984 & 0     & 112.4 & 110.5 & 91.3  & 88.3  & 60    & 58.1  & 54.9  & 55.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
200   & 0.74  & 0     & 112.3 & 110.3 & 91.1  & 88.4  & 60    & 58.3  & 54.9  & 55.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 0.378 & 0     & 111.5 & 109.6 & 90.7  & 89    & 60.3  & 58.5  & 54.9  & 55.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
600   & 0.391 & 0     & 111.7 & 109.6 & 90.9  & 88.8  & 60.8  & 58.9  & 55.1  & 55.9  & 29.5  & 19 \\
799   & 0.344 & 0     & 111.6 & 109.9 & 91.1  & 89.2  & 61.4  & 59.2  & 55.4  & 56.1  & 29.6  & 19 \\
0     & 0.388 & 0     & 111.9 & 110   & 91.6  & 89.3  & 62    & 59.7  & 55.7  & 56.4  & 29.5  & 19 \\
200   & 0.381 & 0     & 112.5 & 110.2 & 92    & 89.5  & 62.7  & 60.2  & 56.1  & 56.8  & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 0.366 & 0     & 112.6 & 110.4 & 92.6  & 89.8  & 63.4  & 60.7  & 56.6  & 57.1  & 29.6  & 19 \\
600   & 0.336 & 0     & 112.9 & 110.7 & 93    & 90.3  & 64    & 61.2  & 57.1  & 57.3  & 29.6  & 19 \\
799   & 0.328 & 0     & 113.1 & 110.9 & 93.6  & 90.6  & 64.6  & 61.8  & 57.5  & 57.5  & 29.6  & 19 \\
0     & 0.329 & 0     & 113.2 & 111.2 & 94.1  & 90.9  & 65.2  & 62.3  & 58    & 57.8  & 29.6  & 19 \\
200   & 0.393 & 0     & 113.4 & 111.4 & 95    & 91.2  & 65.9  & 62.9  & 58.4  & 58    & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 0.362 & 0     & 113.6 & 111.6 & 95.6  & 91.5  & 66.5  & 63.5  & 58.8  & 58.3  & 29.6  & 19 \\
600   & 0.345 & 0     & 113.8 & 111.9 & 96.3  & 91.7  & 67.1  & 64.1  & 59.2  & 58.5  & 29.5  & 19 \\
799   & 0.343 & 0     & 113.9 & 112.1 & 80    & 92    & 67.8  & 64.7  & 59.6  & 58.8  & 29.6  & 19 \\
0     & 0.335 & 0     & 113.9 & 112.4 & 97.6  & 92.2  & 68.4  & 65.4  & 60    & 59    & 29.6  & 19 \\
200   & 0.374 & 0     & 113.2 & 112.6 & 98.3  & 92.6  & 69.2  & 66    & 60.4  & 59.2  & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 0.403 & 0     & 114.6 & 112.9 & 98.9  & 92.8  & 69.7  & 66.6  & 60.7  & 59.5  & 29.6  & 19 \\
600   & 0.381 & 0     & 114.4 & 113.3 & 99.4  & 93.1  & 70.4  & 67.2  & 61.1  & 59.8  & 29.6  & 19.1 \\
799   & 0.388 & 0     & 115   & 113.7 & 100.1 & 93.3  & 71.1  & 67.8  & 61.4  & 60.1  & 29.6  & 19 \\
0     & 0.387 & 0     & 114.7 & 114.2 & 100.8 & 93.4  & 71.8  & 68.4  & 61.5  & 60.3  & 29.5  & 19 \\
200   & 0.41  & 0     & 115.3 & 115   & 101.9 & 93.6  & 72.4  & 69.2  & 61.8  & 60.6  & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 0.41  & 0     & 116.5 & 116.3 & 101.8 & 94    & 73.1  & 69.8  & 62.1  & 60.9  & 29.5  & 19 \\
600   & 0.421 & 0     & 117.5 & 118.6 & 102.3 & 94.3  & 73.7  & 70.4  & 62.4  & 61.2  & 29.5  & 19 \\
799   & 0.431 & 0     & 119.9 & 123.6 & 102.7 & 94.6  & 74.3  & 71.1  & 62.7  & 61.4  & 29.5  & 19 \\
0     & 0.442 & 0     & 125.3 & 132   & 103.3 & 95    & 74.9  & 71.7  & 62.9  & 61.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
200   & 0.448 & 0     & 135.8 & 141.5 & 103.8 & 95.2  & 75.5  & 72.3  & 63.2  & 61.8  & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 0.465 & 0     & 151.1 & 147.4 & 104.4 & 95.6  & 76.1  & 72.9  & 63.5  & 62.1  & 29.5  & 19 \\
600   & 0.485 & 0     & 164.4 & 155.3 & 105.3 & 95.8  & 76.7  & 73.4  & 63.7  & 62.3  & 29.5  & 19 \\
799   & 0.495 & 0     & 181.1 & 175.6 & 106.4 & 96.1  & 77.2  & 74    & 63.9  & 62.5  & 29.5  & 19 \\
0     & 0.55  & 0     & 216.6 & 196.5 & 107.8 & 96.3  & 77.7  & 74.4  & 64    & 62.6  & 29.5  & 19 \\
200   & 0.561 & 0     & 246.8 & 215.1 & 108.1 & 96.6  & 78.3  & 75    & 64.3  & 62.8  & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 0.604 & 0     & 278   & 244   & 174.5 & 96.9  & 78.8  & 75.5  & 64.5  & 63.1  & 29.6  & 19 \\
600   & 0.646 & 0     & 304.2 & 273.1 & 174.1 & 97    & 79.2  & 75.9  & 64.6  & 63.2  & 29.6  & 19 \\
799   & 0.725 & 0     & 326.1 & 284.4 & 173.4 & 97.2  & 79.6  & 76.3  & 64.8  & 63.3  & 29.5  & 19 \\
0     & 0.759 & 0     & 337.3 & 293.5 & 172.5 & 97.3  & 79.9  & 76.6  & 64.9  & 63.4  & 29.5  & 19.1 \\
200   & 0.837 & 0     & 340.7 & 301.8 & 171.8 & 97.5  & 80.3  & 77    & 65.2  & 63.5  & 29.5  & 19 \\
400   & 0.864 & 0     & 342.3 & 306.3 & 170.6 & 97.7  & 80.6  & 77.3  & 65.2  & 63.7  & 29.5  & 19 \\
600   & 0.701 & 0     & 345.4 & 309.7 & 169.7 & 97.9  & 80.9  & 77.5  & 65.4  & 63.8  & 29.5  & 19 \\
799   & 0.876 & 0     & 346.2 & 307.6 & 169.1 & 98.1  & 81.1  & 77.9  & 65.5  & 63.8  & 29.5  & 19 \\
0     & 0.886 & 0     & 343.7 & 306.2 & 168.6 & 98.3  & 81.4  & 78    & 65.7  & 63.9  & 29.5  & 19 \\
200   & 0.876 & 0     & 340.9 & 305.4 & 168   & 98.4  & 81.6  & 78.3  & 65.8  & 64.1  & 29.5  & 19     \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your table is too wide to fit in a page. You may consider using `landscape` mode.

Answer (score 4):

This document compiles if you add `\\` after the `\caption` command, as in

```
\caption{This table shows the volatges and temperatures of the cell immediately before and immediately after cell failure}\\
```